# Autofill select and check box to calculate price

Tags: php, javascript, autofill

I am looking to have a form auto fill and calculate totals based on the options selected for a web page I am constructing. I am new to javascript and found the following code example on this site but could not modify it to work as I would like. Any help would be appreciated. The check boxes will calculate but not the select list.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            var allprices = [];
            var index = 0;

            function chkrads(frmName,rbGroupName) {
                var chosen = "";
                var radios = document[frmName].elements[rbGroupName];
                for (var i=0; i <radios.length; i++) {
                    if (radios[i].checked) {
                        chosen = radios[i].value;
                    }
                }

                if (chosen == 0) {printprice = 0}
                if (chosen == 1) {printprice = 99}
                if (chosen == 2) {printprice = 150}
                if (chosen == 3) {printprice = 250}
                if (chosen == 21) {printprice = 200}
                if (chosen == 22) {printprice = 300}    
                if (chosen == 30) {printprice = 50}    
                if (chosen == 41) {printprice = 50}
                if (chosen == 42) {printprice = 70}
                if (chosen == 43) {printprice = 90}
                if (rbGroupName == "size") {index = 0}
                if (rbGroupName == "colour") {index = 1}
                if (rbGroupName == "frame") {index = 2}
                if (rbGroupName == "glass") {index = 3}
                if (rbGroupName == "hook") {index = 4}
                if (rbGroupName == "delivery") {index = 5}

                allprices[index] = printprice;

                var totalprice = 0;
                for (var i =0; i <allprices.length; i++) {
                    if (!isNaN(allprices[i])) {
                        totalprice = totalprice + allprices[i];
                    }
                }

                document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = totalprice;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name= "myform" style="font-size:11px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
            <select name = "size" onchange = "chkrads('myform', 'size')">
                <option></option>
                <option value = "0">0</option>
                <option value = "1">1</option>
            </select>
            </option><br>
            <br /><br /><br /><br />

            <input type = "radio" name = "colour" value = "0" onclick = "chkrads('myform', 'colour')"><b>No</b>
            <input type = "radio" name = "colour" value = "21" onclick = "chkrads('myform', 'colour')"><b>black</b>
            <input type = "radio" name = "colour" value = "22" onclick = "chkrads('myform','colour')"><b>Multi Colour</b>

            <br /><br /><br /><br />

            <input type = "radio" name = "frame" value = "0" onclick = "chkrads('myform', 'logo')">    <b>No</b>
            <input type = "radio" name = "frame" value = "30" onclick = "chkrads('myform', 'logo')"><b>Yes</b>
            <br /><br /><br /><br />

            <input type = "radio" name = "glass" value = "0" onclick = "chkrads('myform', 'glass')"><b>No</b>
            <input type = "radio" name = "glass" value = "51" onclick = "chkrads('myform',     'glass')"><b>Yes</b>

            <br /><br /><br /><br />

            <input type = "radio" name = "hook" value = "0" onclick = "chkrads('myform', 'hook')">    <b>0</b>
            <input type = "radio" name = "hook" value = "41" onclick = "chkrads('myform', 'hook')">    <b>1</b>
            <input type = "radio" name = "hook" value = "42" onclick = "chkrads('myform', 'hook')">    <b>2</b>
            <input type = "radio" name = "hook" value = "43" onclick = "chkrads('myform', 'hook')">    <b>3</b>

            <br /><br /><br /><br />

            <input type = "radio" name = "delivery" value = "0" onclick = "chkrads('myform',     'delivery')"><b>No</b>
            <input type = "radio" name = "delivery" value = "61" onclick = "chkrads('myform',     'delivery')"><b>Yes</b>

        </form>


        <div id="result" style="display:none;"><strong></strong> <span id="totalprice"></span>     </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that this statement:

```
if (radios[i].checked) {
        chosen = radios[i].value;
```

only sets "chosen" if the element is a checkbox.

Try this instead:

```
if (radios[i].checked || radios[i].selected) {
        chosen = radios[i].value;
```

I set up a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ARqQr/3/

On a side note, this looks like something that would be very easily solved using [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) and might tidy the code up a bit...

Comment: One last question, if I change the above code and add chosen2 for a different set of values from the selection list the javascript will not function.

Comment: although I assign values to the new var